# ParsePy - Filter results that contain string

Tags: python, regex, django, parse-platform

I have a table stored in Parse.com, and I'm using ParsePy to get and filter the data in my Python Django program.

My table has three columns, `objectId` (string), `name` (string), and `type` (array). I want to query the name column and return any objects that contain the partial term `xyz`. For example, if I search for `amp`, and there's a row where `name: Example Name` this row should be returned.

Here's my code so far:

```
def searchResults(self, searchTerm):
        register('parseKey', 'parseRestKey')
        myParseObject = ParseObject()

        allData = myParseObject.Query.filter(name = searchTerm)
        return allData
```

The problem with this code is it only works if `searchTerm` is exactly the same as what's in the `name` column. The Parse REST API says that the queries accept regex parameters, but I'm not sure how to use them in ParsePy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use regex for that. And, this is how it would be:

```
     allData = myParseObject.Query.filter(name__regex = "<your_regex>")
```